# Freestyle, render some objects with dashed lines and others with solid lines?

Tags: freestyle

I have two objects in my scene.  I'm using Freestyle.  I can't figure out how to make it so that Object 1 renders with a dashed (or dotted) outline, while Object 2 simultaneously renders with a solid outline.  I tried a lot of different settings - unfortunately, every time I select an object and change the Freestyle Line Set or Freestyle Line Style settings for it, it seems to apply the change to both objects.

(FWIW, when I change the Material for one object, it only changes the Material for that object.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

### Use [Groups](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/relationships/groups.html?highlight=groups)

Freestyle has an option to apply the Line Set to a previusly created group. You just habe to enable it in the **Selection by** section and pick **Groups**. An empty fields will appear below where you can choose what groups will be affected by the linestyle options.

[image]

In the image above each cube belongs to a different group (you can see them in the outliner), and each of the two Line Set is targeting one of them.

You can group the selected objects by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and select all the objects with the same material (or something else) with [Select linked](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-linked)

---

What I presented is probably the most versatile way, but you can probably get a similar result by taking advantage of one of the other ways in which you can restrict the Line Style influence (e.g. you can hide your dotted object and use the **Visibilty** options...).