# Unable to create a dashed edges with Freestyle

Tags: edges, freestyle, wireframe

I am trying to make an object that is rendered in wireframe with dashed edges. So far I am working on a model which is using Freestyle. I have tried a lot of settings but still not achieving what I want.

So here's my model

[image: My model. A black wireframe on top of a white plane.]

Which I am hoping to look like this

[image: A drawn black dashed wireframe.]

So here are my settings

[image]
[image]

The material I used, FYI.

[image]

My question is: 
**How can I make my model with black dashed lines?**

Comment: Hello :). this thread should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170301

Comment: I looked at your answer in that question, but still the dashed lines were nor apparent to me. Still working on it.

Comment: @jachym-michal Just to confirm in your answer (step 3), is what I did above right?