# How do I get freestyle lines to render "behind" a mesh?

Tags: edges, freestyle, compositing-nodes

I'm using freestyle to create thick, bold black outlines around my models. I use a line set with **external contour** edge type at a high thickness value. The problem I am having is that my freestyle lines occlude my models at render time. Here's a simple example of what I'm talking about.

[image]

This is a zoomed crop of one cube intersecting another. The freestyle line is drawn in red. You'll notice that the external contour line clips into the corner and edges of the two intersecting cubes.

I'm a beginner so I am not sure what the proper terms or workflows are called. But what I want to be able to do is (1) render the freestyle separately, (2) render the model separately, and (3) combine the two, with the model "on top" or "in front" of the freestyle lines. This way, the freestyle lines won't "subtract" from the model's contour. Is this possible? Are render layers and compositing what I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is an example of using Freestyle and the Compositor that might be of use: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170301/how-can-i-freestyle-render-outlines-but-remove-the-object-itself