# Freestyle renders broken contours

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I have been playing with freestyle lately. I end up with the following wrong rendering with discontinuous contours on the blue shapes and I really don't understand why. The freestyle setting are showed below. I found some similar old problems on the forum, but did not find any solution that work for me. The render is done with Eevee, but Cylces does not improve the problem.

Thank you very much for your help!

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: Thank you Robin, I added the file to the post. I slightly improved the situation by rescaling the big surface, but that is still problematic.

Comment: I thikn this is Freestyle's version of Z-fighting - stroked edges exactly coincident with faces. You could, as you have, disambiguate by slightly scaling/moving.. but that's a faff for each case. I think a cleaner solution would be to separate the render into layers and composite them, like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170331/35559). If this link is not sufficient, I can flesh out an answer for your case?

Comment: Thank you Robin! I kind of see what this post is about, but does it mean that I cannot do it in Eevee? Also, it looks like I will filter out all surfaces from the pictures, my blue planes as well. Maybe I missed something here.

Comment: The Freestyle-only passes would have to be in Cycles atm, (not sure about 2.9 .. will look up),, The surfaces come back in composite,, The cost is not high, 32 samples enough, I thought.